# Re-name excel sheets based on their names

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet

Say I have the following worksheet names:

> *Test, Test_Only, TS_051, TS_052, TS_053, TS_054, etc*

and want to dynamically re-name the ones with the numbers and end-up with something like:

> *Test, Test_Only, TS_60, TS_61, TS_62, TS_63*

I wish manually re-naming the sheets were an option however the file I have has more than a thousand. Also want to note that the names just add incrementally by '1'

Comment: what is your code you've tried so far?

Comment: The sheets are already created and you just want to rename them?  Or you wish to copy a template sheet and give it an ordinal number starting at TS_60?

Comment: Are there Sheets that you dont want to rename between the numbered sheets?

Answer (score 0):

This works as long as you know where to begin and there are no other tables between the ones you want to change. (not so hard to add)

```
Sub tableNames()

Dim wsi As Worksheet

'Set the value to the id of first sheet you want to rename

i = 1

Do While i < ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count + 1

Set wsi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
'change this String if you want another name
wsi.Name = ("TS_" & i)

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```